# Bullet Physics Simulation Running Slow

Tags: c++, bullet-physics, visual-studio

I'm in the process of converting my game engine from java which used the LWJGL and JBullet to c++. However, when I was implementing Bullet physics my simple simulation of a box dropping from specified height onto a plane ran very slowly.

After scouring the forms I came across two possible solutions:

1. Compiling my simulation in release mode rather than debug.
2. Enabling compiler optimizations for speed.

After building in release and enabling the compiler optimizations my simulation still runs at the same speed. I've tested the FPS which usually runs between 400-350fps and that the simulations was stepped each frame. I can't find anyone that has had the same problem as me and I can't understand why JBullet which is a java port of the Bullet Physics Library runs fine on the same PC. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what timestep are you using and how do you calculate the time-difference?

Comment: Do you use bullets release libs? What frame time do you get?

Comment: if you are rendering the results, is vsync on?